# CodeBuild with custom docker image get error: Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, devops, aws-codebuild

I created a docker image:

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2 AS core
WORKDIR /root
RUN yum update -y
RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN yum install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g less coffeescript
#shodw-utils for use the useradd command.
RUN yum install shadow-utils -y
RUN useradd ec2-user
RUN yum install -y awslogs
RUN yum -y install net-tools
RUN yum install which -y
RUN yum install sudo -y
RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install nginx -y
RUN yum clean metadata
RUN yum install -y python3-devel.aarch64
RUN yum install python37
RUN /usr/bin/pip3.7 install virtualenv
RUN virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.7 /var/app/.venv
RUN yum install nginx -y
RUN yum -y groupinstall Development tools
RUN yum -y install zlib-devel
RUN yum -y install bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel
RUN yum -y install sqlite sqlite-devel xz-devel
RUN yum -y install readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel
RUN yum -y install libpcap-devel xz-devel
RUN yum -y install libjpeg-devel
RUN yum -y install wget
```

When i run it with privileged on my local it succeed to run NGINX service with no failure.

CodeBuild (Privileged mode= True) pull this image from ECR but when trying to run NGINX service i got the following error:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

any ideas?

Comment: How are you running the container, in both setups?  If the goal of the container is to run Nginx then why are you installing Python, NCurses, several C development packages, and Systemd?  (If nothing else, remove Systemd from this setup, since it wants to manage a huge number of host-level things, and it's probably the reason you need a privileged container at all.)

Comment: The docker suppose to be with python and nginx installed. 
then the codebuild pull the image and use python and start nginx service.
Locally it working fine.

Comment: That sounds like it's a setup that would normally be in two containers -- one running the Nginx proxy, one running the Python application, no systemd, and no need for a privileged container.  Needing the privileged container is unusual and it seems like the source of your trouble, can you remove the privileged option (which probably means removing systemd)?

Comment: I understand what u saying, but i must have them both. 
It worked to me before. the only change i made with the docker image that instead of running on amazonlinux2:64_86x it running on ARM64